# "Going to" VS "having gone to" in this context

Tags: grammaticality

> Going to the stadium, I saw Tendulkar was batting.
>
> Having gone to the stadium, I saw Tendulkar was batting.

As a learner I know that the former is present participle and the latter is perfect participle.

But people often interchange with each other

Are they interchangeable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Going to the stadium, I saw Tendulkar was batting.

it means while you were going to the stadium, you saw Tendulkar was batting.

> Having gone to the stadium, I saw Tendulkar was batting.

it means after you had reached the stadium, you saw Tendulkar was batting.
They are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

'Going to the stadium' refers to the journey to the stadium; 'having gone to the stadium' refers to an event at, or after, the time you arrived at the stadium.

Going to the stadium, I saw on a TV in a shop that Tendulkar was batting.

Having gone to the stadium, I saw on the pitch that Tendulkar was batting.

Comment: Please explain in context of the given example